# Trying to set up monitor at increased resolution

Tags: raspbian

So I am trying to set up a monitor with a higher resolution using;

hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=77

But when I boot, I the monitor reverts to 1920x1080 i.e. hdmt_mode 82

Is there a location where I can add a resolution to the file associated with the attached monitor.  I appreciate the monitor may not support this mode, but I would like to be able to add a custom mode to the list of available modes for the monitor, hence wanting to identify and locate the specific file that is read by the Pi configuration app.

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome! Maybe helpful: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: What is the max resolution of your monitor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of the video modes shown in the documentation are supported -- which begs the question why they are shown at all.  In any case, underneath [the table for group 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) there's a note:

> Note that there is [a pixel clock limit](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=20155&p=195443#p195443). The highest supported mode is 1920x1200 at 60Hz with reduced blanking.

If you click through the link, you will find a Pi Foundation forum thread where an Engineer makes it explicit:

> That is the list of all the standard CEA/DMT modes. Additionally there is a pixel clock limit which means **modes bigger than 1920x1200@60 are not supported.**

Comment: "why they are shown at all" good point, maybe someone finds spare time to edit the page on https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md