# Pi3 freezes on boot when display_rotate=1

Tags: hdmi, kernel

I've been struggling with an issue with my Pi. I have a 2560 x 1440p HDMI screen that i've been trying to get to work. After getting the HDMI timings and settings from the manufacturer it shows the console on screen however the screen is rotated 90 degrees.

So in order to to fix that issue I have been trying to get display_rotate=1 to work. However, every time I set display_rotate=1 in the /boot/config.txt file when the Pi boots it freezes on the square rainbow screen and becomes completely unresponsive. (No SSH access)

When display_rotate=1 is not set the Pi boots normally.

I have tried different HDMI setting combinations, reinstalling stretch lite, enabling/disabling KMS hardware acceleration.

/boot/config.txt contents

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details    

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1    

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1    

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16    

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720    

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1    

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1    

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2    

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4    

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2    

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800    

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on    

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi    

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README    

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on    

# screen settings
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_timings=1440 0 70 35 45 2560 0 12 2 2 0 0 0 50 0 204792000 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=300000000
hvs_priority=0x32ff    

max_framebuffer_width=1440
max_framebuffer_height=2560
framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1440
framebuffer_depth=24
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
config_hdmi_boost=4    

#display_rotate=1.
```

tvservice -s result

```
state 0x12000a [HDMI DMT (87) RGB full unknown AR], 1440x2560 @ 50.00Hz, progressive
```

Screen EDID data

```
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, unknown aspect ratio
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend !active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is V_R__________$?
HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 23-75 Hz, horizontal is 15-240 kHz, max pixel clock is 300 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 00 00 00
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:no, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:4
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 50 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1440x2560p @50 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 1440x2560p hfp:60 hs:10 hbp:35 vfp:4 vs:1 vbp:3 pixel clock:198 MHz
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID does not understand CEA format code 0
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48|88|96|176|192 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 6
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 3.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports AI:yes, dual link DVI:no
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB deep colour support - 48-bit:no 36-bit:no 30-bit:no DC_yuv444:no
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no latency information
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID no known preferred format has been set
HDMI:EDID filtering preferred group has been changed from Invalid to CEA
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
HDMI:EDID preferred mode is updated to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25200000 Hz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edidparser exited with code 0
```

Comment: The settings in your config.txt are nonsense and contradictory remove them and see what happens. Do NOT use display rotate (I will post a more detailed explanation when I am at a computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the function of `display_rotate`. This does not change the HDMI output, but transposes the pixels in the frame buffer. This enables a display to be physically rotated and display in portrait mode. (I use this on a monitor with a rotatable screen.)

You have framebuffer_width=2560 BUT max_framebuffer_width=1440 - these settings have to be consistent.

Your fundamental problem, however, is that your monitor would require the Pi to exceed its maximum pixel clock rate. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/83421/8697

There has been some discussion about increasing the pixel clock on the Pi, but I have never tried this.

Your options are to select a HDMI mode that the Pi can support - either lower resolution or lower frame rate.

Comment: You are a life saver, I have been staring so long at that config that I stopped seeing things like this. I changed the max buffer sizes both to 2560 and edited the framerate to 30Hz in the timings and that fixed it.